# Missing objectID in JWT returned by Azure AD ADAL request

Tags: adal, azure-active-directory

We are implementing Azure AD authentication for our native app using ADAL

We have the native app authenticate against Azure AD using ADAL and pass the returned JWT on to our web app for validation and logging into the appropriate account.

We are running into an issue in that the JWT returned using ADAL does not contain the objectID of the user.

We are guessing that this either have to do with how we have configured our Azure AD native app and/or the parameters we are passing ADAL authentcation request.

Does anybody have any suggestions for what we may configured wrong.

Comment: which ADAL library/platform are you using?

Comment: Would you mind show the exact claims in the token here? You can parse it from this [site](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: Thanks for the link to https://jwt.io/
The clams are (need to break it into two pieces as it is otherwise too long):
{
  "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/39f8b586-1a6c-413e-9fd3-70b57a1d9fa0/",
  "iat": 1476374822,
  "nbf": 1476374822,
  "exp": 1476378722,
  "acr": "1",
  "altsecid": "5::10037FFE8DC424C2",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "appid": "635034ea-2fb2-4906-b3d4-88a6c3549c1a",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "e_exp": 10800,
  "email": "test.user69@smartsheet365.onmicrosoft.com",
  "family_name": "User 69",
  "given_name": "Test",

Comment: Remaining part
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/3836f4a1-67af-43f2-a675-f9f54899abe0/",
  "ipaddr": "67.139.42.217",
  "name": "Test User 69",
  "scp": "User.Read",
  "sub": "5cH526r4VK-3TCy_kLq1Ut5YX-_J2ak-AN3xyLOELs4",
  "tid": "39f8b586-1a6c-413e-9fd3-70b57a1d9fa0",
  "unique_name": "test.user69@smartsheet365.onmicrosoft.com",
  "ver": "1.0"
}

Comment: Hi Niels - is this tenant federated with an on-prem AD/ADFS by any chance? Looks to me like it is not, but I wanted to double check.  Is test.user69 just a normal user that you created in your tenant via the Azure Portal?

Comment: Also, what is the value for authority that you are passing into ADAL?

Comment: Firstly: no, it is not federated. All users have been created using the Azure Portal

Comment: We are using 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/39f8b586-1a6c-413e-9fd3-70b57a1d9fa0/oauth2/authorize 
as authority, which we got from the app endpoints, but I now realize it says  OAuth 2.0 Authorization Endpoint
What should we be using?

Answer (score 0):

When you get a token like this from Azure AD, it's called a "passthrough" token.  Technically, it means the user that the token represents did not have a presence in the tenant in which authentication occurred.  Tell-tale signs of a passthrough token is the lack of `oid` claim, the existence of an `idp` claim, the existence of an `altsecid` claim, and most imporantly, an `idp` claim whose value does not match the `iss` claim.

3rd party applications should never receive passthrough tokens from Azure AD.  In this case, the token is intended for the app with ID `00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`, which is not your app.  It's the Microsoft Graph or the AAD Graph (I forget which).  You should **never ever ever** be validating tokens whose `aud` claim is not your application.  At any point in time, the owner of that app could change the token format and completely break your application.  Instead, you should use the `AppID URI` of your application as the `resource` parameter you pass to ADAL, and send the resulting token to your web service.  We have lots of sample at aka.ms/aaddev that show you how to create your own web APIs.

With all that said, I don't think that is your problem here. It looks like you are signing in the user against the tenant `39f8b586-1a6c-413e-9fd3-70b57a1d9fa0`, the "Mars Feature 3 Native" tenant.  This is probably the value you are passing into ADAL's `authority` parameter.  So when you sign in test.user69@smartsheet365.onmicrosoft.com, they are passed through the Mars tenant to your app (because the token is not for your app).  Instead, you should use tenant `3836f4a1-67af-43f2-a675-f9f54899abe0`, the smartsheet365.onmicrosoft.com tenant.  Then you should be back to getting normal user tokens from Azure AD.

Comment: Maybe we have misunderstood the configuration of the Azure AD apps needed.

We have a multi-tenant app that we are using for OAuth2 authentication for our web app.

In addition we created a native Azure app for native app through ADAL. Our understanding was that we need to do so when using iOS ADAL.
This is the app with id 635034ea-2fb2-4906-b3d4-88a6c3549c1a of tenant 39f8b586-1a6c-413e-9fd3-70b57a1d9fa0 
The next reply will contain the attributes of this app.

Comment: App attributes:

clientID: 635034ea-2fb2-4906-b3d4-88a6c3549c1a

redirectURLs: x-msauth-smartsheet://com.smartsheet.smartsheet/ and msauth://code/x-msauth-smartsheet%3A%2F%2Fcom.smartsheet.smartsheet

resource: 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000

authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/39f8b586-1a6c-413e-9fd3-70b57a1d9fa0/oauth2/authorize

Is this a wrong approach?

Comment: If you want to sign in users from any Azure AD tenant, use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common´ as the authority.

Comment: I do have a follow up question to help us test the server part without having the native app completed.

Comment: Is there a way that we can generate the kind of JWT generated by the ADAL request so we can test our server code independently of calling it from a native app?